# How to delay popup modal content loading until its opening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a very heavy `<iframe>` object that is embedded into a popup modal. However, the `<iframe>` object is loaded together with the main page where the modal is located (as it should be normally). Is it possible somehow to prevent `<iframe>` from loading unless the modal which contains it is opened by the user?

The modal itself currently looks like this:

```
<div id="popup" class="slickModal">
    <div class="window">
        <iframe width="1062" height="600" src="https://my.matterport.com/show/?m=XXXXXXXXXX" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
    </div>
</div>
```

My number one objective is to keep the page loading speed as low as possible. Currently the page itself without this popup modal weighs under 800KB but the heavy `<iframe>` object increases it to 4MB+.

Is there a different kind of popup modal system that loads its content only when opened or is there something that can be done with the current one?

Comment: Leave `iframe`'s `src` empty and set it on `show.bs.modal` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
<div id="popup" class="slickModal">
    <div class="window"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and your script to

```
$(function(){
$('#popup').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { 
$('<iframe>', {
   src: 'https://my.matterport.com/show/?m=XXXXXXXXXX',
   width:'1062',
   height: '600',
   id:  'myFrame',
   frameborder: 0  
   }).appendTo('.window'); 
});
})
```

Comment: I forgot to mentioned that is not a bootstrap modal that I am using, however this solution worked perfectly. I used onClick="" attribute within the anchor tag that launches my modal.